# Where can I find change log for NuGet package System.Memory?

Tags: nuget-package, release-notes, system.memory

The .NET NuGet package `System.Memory` has 2.3 billion downloads, but the release notes tab at https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory contains a link to https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/main/release-notes which does not appear to contain the release notes for this library but instead for .NET Core.

How can I determine what the difference is between version 4.5.4 and 4.5.5 of this NuGet package? I understand I can disassembly it and diff the versions myself, but I would think that a package with 2.3 billion downloads would have some kind of release notes.

Comment: You also asked this on github: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/8714  (Just as a reference for future visitors interested in this subject)